# GridView - show last added record as first displayed

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

Just like in the title. I got GridView control that displaying some data from database. All i want to do is to make GridView displaying rows descending, i mean from the last added to first added. So first row i see from the GridView is displaying the last item added to database instead of added first like is in default state. I hope you understand what i mean ;).

Im pretty sure there is a property for that but i cant find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about any property for reversing the gridview itself, but you can always reverse the datasource ;) If you're displaying a data from db, include that in your sql/linq query.

Comment: OF course. I forgot about it that i can do it by changing select query ;). Thank You very much for the tip :).